# Finding all positive integers $n$ such that $\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5\}$ partitions into two subsets such that the products of elements are the same

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

Question from 12th IMO:

> Find all positive integers $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that the set
> $\{n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, n + 4, n + 5\}$
> can be split into two disjoint subsets such that the products of elements in these subsets are the same.

It seems simple to me, yet I can't find the solution.
Edit: I have found no such examples.

Comment: Do you know any such $n$?

Comment: @Richardfeynman They are asking for several reasons. Here are the ones I can think of. Reason 1: Looking for an example might very well reveal the underlying concepts you are after. Reason 2: It is a small thing you can do to demonstrate that you have made an effort to solve this before you came here. Reason 3 (related to reason 2): We really want question posts here to contain [more than just a problem statement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: You are asking a question. You should provide the motivation  and show your efforts. Otherwise, if the motivation and efforts are not obvious, a question is considered "bad". Also it is bad sign when the original poster disrespects people asking questions about the post.

Comment: And of course you know that all IMO problems with solutions can be easily found on the Web.

Comment: For example, https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1970_IMO_Problems/Problem_4 has two solutions of the problem you posted here.

Comment: @Richardfeynman It's an IMO problem. The actual pattern is possibly quite complicated. But there are partial patterns you could discover. For instance, $n$ _must_ be divisible by $5$. That's an underlying pattern you can find relatively easily. And if you had pointed this out in your post, we would've been much happier.

Comment: The other observation that should be a key is that at most one of the factors can be divisible by seven or eleven, which is a no cigar situation. The rest should be simple case work.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I have made a comment with a link to two solutions. Both are quite trivial.

Comment: In case somebody wants solutions of other IMO problems. These can be found here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/IMO_Problems_and_Solutions

Comment: @JCAA Thanks from the bottom of my heart for your solutions. Please don't mind for my comments.

Comment: If one of the six numbers is divisible by $7$, then it is the only one.  Therefore, no matter how we split the six numbers, the product of one set is divisible by $7$, but the product of the other set is not.  $$\ $$  If none of the six numbers is divisible by $7$, then they are $1,2,3,4,5,6$ modulo $7$.  The product of all six numbers is $6!\equiv -1\pmod{7}$, which is not a quadratic residue modulo $7$.  What can you say from this conclusion?  $$\ $$  However, in general, the product of consecutive positive integers is never a perfect power.  This was proven by Erdős and Selfridge in 1974.

Comment: Woopsie. You are right, of course, @BrianMoehring. I only got my morning coffee a minute ago :-)

Comment: This question [was asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948239/find-the-set-of-n-in-bbb-z-with-m-n-n1-n2-n3-n4-n5-partitionable/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that $n+2$ divides the product of the rest of the numbers, and hence divides $(-2)(-1)(1)(2)(3)=12$. Similarly, $n+3$ divides $-12$, and hence, divides $12$. Both can hold simultaneously only if $n=1$. We can easily see that this fails (since only one of the values is divisible by $5$). Thus, there are no solutions in positive integers.